# Workaround on JCE can't authenticate the provider

Tags: java, jce

I'm running a set of tests on my custom JCE provider implemention (XYZProvider).
Most of my tests are failing with the following error:-

`java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider XYZProvider`

I have installed (i.e. placed provider's jar file) outside of system JRE (I need to stick to this, can't install in JRE) and maybe this is the reason I'm getting this error.
I have tried to search on this error without much success, tried using 
`grant codeBase "//location of my provider class files" { permission java.security.AllPermission; }` in java.security file to give the necessary permission but with no luck.

Have already added the following line in java.security
`security.provider.9=com.ingrian.security.nae.XYZProvider`

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: The permission you tried goes to *java.policy* file, in *java.security* file you need to add your provider implementation in a *security.provider.X=* line

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that. I have already added this line.